# C# Entity Framework 4.1 Lambda Include - only select specific included values

Tags: c#, lambda, include, entity-framework-4.1

I'm doing a lambda select on EF4.1, including another related DBSet in my current statement.

```
 return dbEntity.GameTypes.Include(a => a.Draws)
                           .Where(d => d.IsActive == true )
                           .ToList();
```

I've got two classes:

```
//simplified versions of the classes
public class GameType
{
 public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Draw> Draws { get; set; }
}

public class Draw
{
 public int DrawID { get; set; }
 public int GameTypeID { get; set; }
 public System.DateTime DrawDate { get; set; }
}
```

But I only want the next upcoming draw for each GameType. Essentially I want to do something like

```
 return dbEntity.GameTypes.Include(a => a.Draws.Where(aw => aw.DrawDate > System.DateTime.Now)
                                               .OrderBy(ao => ao.DrawDate)
                                               .First())
                           .Where(d => d.IsActive == true )
                           .ToList();
```

But it gives me:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dottedpaths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Is something like this possible or would I need to filter the result afterwards? I'd then also like to order the total result by the latest Draw.DrawDate. If anyone could show me the proper way I'd be trully gratefull.

Comment: You can do .Include on navigational properties only. Peter Hancock's query is fine, except you do not need to do an Include in that query.

Comment: I think that depends on whether lazy loading and proxy creation are enabled - if they are, the Include isn't needed - if they're not, then the include is

Comment: From EntityFramework 4.1 you must use System.Data.Entity: using System.Data.Entity ... MyDBContext.MySet.Include(o => o.MyAssociation)

Answer (score 2):

I think....

```
    from g in dbEntity.GameTypes.Include("Draws")
   where g.IsActive
     let d = g.Draws.Where(o => o.DrawDate > System.DateTime.Now)
                    .OrderBy(o => o.DrawDate)
                    .Take(1)       // Needs to stay a collection
  select new GameType {IsActive = g.IsActive, Draws = d}
```

untested - but it might get you on the right path...

Comment: I think this would still bring down all the associated `Draws`.

Comment: I don't think so - Draws is being filtered by DrawDate > Now, and then ordered, before `Take(1)`

Comment: You do not need to do .Include here in the first line

Comment: That depends on whether the context has lazy loading and proxy creation turned on.  Given that the original request had the include, I'd suggest that proxy creation and lazy loading is turned off => requiring the include.

Comment: Thanks Peter. It did give a few errors, but decided to not spend too much time playing with it. In terms of performance and what I need it to do, I decided best would just be to create a SProc and a relating complex type.

Comment: This is mostly correct answer. You cannot filter or order included related entities. If you want to filter or order related entities you must use projection. Once you use projection you don't need `Include`.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN for [`DbExtensions.Include()`](http://207.46.16.248/en-us/library/gg671236%28VS.103%29.aspx).

> The path expression must be composed
>   of simple property access expressions
>   together with calls to Select in order
>   to compose additional includes after
>   including a collection property.

So I don't think using `Where()` is allowed. I'm not sure if you can do any filtering when it comes to `Include()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've never been successful at finding a way to filter the children like you want to do. In order to reduce the volume of data being retrieved from the database I will usually retrieve just the parent objects and then loop over them getting only the children I want and "attach" them to the parent. That's not a hard-and-fast rule though, it kind of depends on how many children there are for each parent and what percentage of them I'm likely to want to keep.